# Antlr parser rule fails to match either of specified lexer rules

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have a small work-in-progress Antlr grammar that looks like:

```
filterExpression returns [ActivityPredicate pred]
    : NAME OPERATOR (PACE | NUMBER) {
        if ($PACE != null) {
            $pred = new SingleActivityPredicate($NAME.text, Operator.fromCharacter($OPERATOR.text), $PACE.text);
        } else {
            $pred = new SingleActivityPredicate($NAME.text, Operator.fromCharacter($OPERATOR.text), $NUMBER.text);
        }
    };

OPERATOR: ('>' | '<' | '=') ;

NAME: ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+ ;

NUMBER: ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)? ;

PACE: ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')? ':' ('0'..'5')('0'..'9');

WS: (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n')+ -> skip;
```

Hoping to parse things like:

`distance = 4` or `pace < 8:30`

However, both of those inputs result in `null` for *both* the `PACE` and `NUMBER`, while trying to parse either:

[image]

However, dropping the option and just picking `PACE` works fine (it also works fine the other way, opting for `NUMBER`):

```
filterExpression returns [ActivityPredicate pred]
        : NAME OPERATOR PACE { ... };
```

[image]

Why is it that when I provide the option, they're both `null`?

Comment: I think you need a rule ```Skip : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;``` to skip white spaces.  And the rule PACE should be ```PACE: ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')? ':' ('0'..'5')?('0'..'9');```

Comment: I accidentally left out the `WS` rule from my question, added it. I also fixed the `PACE` rule, but am still encountering the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
filterExpression returns [ActivityPredicate pred]
    : n=NAME o=OPERATOR (p=PACE | i=NUMBER) {
        if ($PACE != null) {
            $pred = new SingleActivityPredicate(
                $n.text, Operator.fromCharacter($o.text), $p.text);
        } else {
            $pred = new SingleActivityPredicate(
                $n.text, Operator.fromCharacter($o.text), $i.text);
        }
    };
```